# what is this command in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am new to verilog and I was reading few codes online. I came across the following  line of code and didn't understand what exactly this means

`wr_ptr_reg <= {ADDR_WIDTH + 1{1'b0}};`

I would appreciate if someone could explain what it means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1'b0` describes a 1-bit wide binary zero value. `<n>{<value>}` gives a bit vector formed by concatenating `n` copies of the bit vector `value`. In this case, it creates a bit vector containing `ADDR_WIDTH + 1` copies of `0` bits. `ADDR_WIDTH` will be a previously declared parameter representing some constant value (probably stored as an `integer`, which is basically a 32-bit bit vector). Then you are storing zero to `wr_ptr_reg`. `<=` indicates a non-blocking assignment. This basically means that its value will not be updated until the rest of the current block is finished. You can treat all non-blocking assignments in a block as if they happen at the same time when the block finishes.

It would be much clearer to add parenthesis:

```
wr_ptr_reg <= {(ADDR_WIDTH + 1){1'b0}};
```

Answer (score 2):

`{..}` is a concatenation operator. `{ count { vector } }` means concatenate the `vector` `count` times.

In this case the vector is a single bit which is repeated ADDR_WIDTH + 1 times. 
Thus you get a vector consisting of (ADDR_WIDTH + 1) zeros.

This is another example: `{ 4 { 3'b101} }` is equal to `12'b101101101101`

Thus you set the `wr_ptr_reg` to all zero's (assuming `wr_ptr_reg` consists of ADDR_WIDTH + 1 bits)